# vim does not highlight some c++ keywords

Tags: c++, vim, syntax-highlighting, vi, vim-syntax-highlighting

I use `vim` (installed on `cygwin`) to write `c++` programs but it does not highlight some `c++` keywords such as `new`, `delete`, `public`, `friend`, `try`, but highlight others such as `namespace`, `int`, `const`, `operator`, `true`, `class`, `include`. It also not change color of operators.

I never changed its syntax file. What's wrong with it?
Thanks a lot.

I use a customized color scheme; when I change it to `desert` color scheme, highlighting has no problem, but I need to use that color scheme and can't change it to something else.

I want it show program as the following picture(I used this color scheme with notepad++ in the picture):

[image: example of correctly colored one]

but now it's as the following picture:
[image: not correctly colored one]

the `colorscheme` is here:

```
"Tomorrow Night Bright - Full Colour and 256 Colour
" http://chriskempson.com
"
" Hex colour conversion functions borrowed from the theme "Desert256""

 " Default GUI Colours
 let s:foreground = "eaeaea"
 let s:background = "000000"
 let s:selection = "424242"
 let s:line = "2a2a2a"
 let s:comment = "969896"
 let s:red = "d54e53"
 let s:orange = "e78c45"
 let s:yellow = "e7c547"
 let s:green = "b9ca4a"
 let s:aqua = "70c0b1"
 let s:blue = "7aa6da"
 let s:purple = "c397d8"
 let s:window = "4d5057"

 set background=dark
 hi clear
 syntax reset

 let g:colors_name = "Tomorrow-Night-Bright"

 if has("gui_running") || &t_Co == 88 || &t_Co == 256
" Returns an approximate grey index for the given grey level
fun <SID>grey_number(x)
    if &t_Co == 88
        if a:x < 23
            return 0
        elseif a:x < 69
            return 1
        elseif a:x < 103
            return 2
        elseif a:x < 127
            return 3
        elseif a:x < 150
            return 4
        elseif a:x < 173
            return 5
        elseif a:x < 196
            return 6
        elseif a:x < 219
            return 7
        elseif a:x < 243
            return 8
        else
            return 9
        endif
    else
        if a:x < 14
            return 0
        else
            let l:n = (a:x - 8) / 10
            let l:m = (a:x - 8) % 10
            if l:m < 5
                return l:n
            else
                return l:n + 1
            endif
        endif
    endif
endfun

" Returns the actual grey level represented by the grey index
fun <SID>grey_level(n)
    if &t_Co == 88
        if a:n == 0
            return 0
        elseif a:n == 1
            return 46
        elseif a:n == 2
            return 92
        elseif a:n == 3
            return 115
        elseif a:n == 4
            return 139
        elseif a:n == 5
            return 162
        elseif a:n == 6
            return 185
        elseif a:n == 7
            return 208
        elseif a:n == 8
            return 231
        else
            return 255
        endif
    else
        if a:n == 0
            return 0
        else
            return 8 + (a:n * 10)
        endif
    endif
endfun

" Returns the palette index for the given grey index
fun <SID>grey_colour(n)
    if &t_Co == 88
        if a:n == 0
            return 16
        elseif a:n == 9
            return 79
        else
            return 79 + a:n
        endif
    else
        if a:n == 0
            return 16
        elseif a:n == 25
            return 231
        else
            return 231 + a:n
        endif
    endif
endfun

" Returns an approximate colour index for the given colour level
fun <SID>rgb_number(x)
    if &t_Co == 88
        if a:x < 69
            return 0
        elseif a:x < 172
            return 1
        elseif a:x < 230
            return 2
        else
            return 3
        endif
    else
        if a:x < 75
            return 0
        else
            let l:n = (a:x - 55) / 40
            let l:m = (a:x - 55) % 40
            if l:m < 20
                return l:n
            else
                return l:n + 1
            endif
        endif
    endif
endfun

" Returns the actual colour level for the given colour index
fun <SID>rgb_level(n)
    if &t_Co == 88
        if a:n == 0
            return 0
        elseif a:n == 1
            return 139
        elseif a:n == 2
            return 205
        else
            return 255
        endif
    else
        if a:n == 0
            return 0
        else
            return 55 + (a:n * 40)
        endif
    endif
endfun

" Returns the palette index for the given R/G/B colour indices
fun <SID>rgb_colour(x, y, z)
    if &t_Co == 88
        return 16 + (a:x * 16) + (a:y * 4) + a:z
    else
        return 16 + (a:x * 36) + (a:y * 6) + a:z
    endif
endfun

" Returns the palette index to approximate the given R/G/B colour levels
fun <SID>colour(r, g, b)
    " Get the closest grey
    let l:gx = <SID>grey_number(a:r)
    let l:gy = <SID>grey_number(a:g)
    let l:gz = <SID>grey_number(a:b)

    " Get the closest colour
    let l:x = <SID>rgb_number(a:r)
    let l:y = <SID>rgb_number(a:g)
    let l:z = <SID>rgb_number(a:b)

    if l:gx == l:gy && l:gy == l:gz
        " There are two possibilities
        let l:dgr = <SID>grey_level(l:gx) - a:r
        let l:dgg = <SID>grey_level(l:gy) - a:g
        let l:dgb = <SID>grey_level(l:gz) - a:b
        let l:dgrey = (l:dgr * l:dgr) + (l:dgg * l:dgg) + (l:dgb * l:dgb)
        let l:dr = <SID>rgb_level(l:gx) - a:r
        let l:dg = <SID>rgb_level(l:gy) - a:g
        let l:db = <SID>rgb_level(l:gz) - a:b
        let l:drgb = (l:dr * l:dr) + (l:dg * l:dg) + (l:db * l:db)
        if l:dgrey < l:drgb
            " Use the grey
            return <SID>grey_colour(l:gx)
        else
            " Use the colour
            return <SID>rgb_colour(l:x, l:y, l:z)
        endif
    else
        " Only one possibility
        return <SID>rgb_colour(l:x, l:y, l:z)
    endif
endfun

" Returns the palette index to approximate the 'rrggbb' hex string
fun <SID>rgb(rgb)
    let l:r = ("0x" . strpart(a:rgb, 0, 2)) + 0
    let l:g = ("0x" . strpart(a:rgb, 2, 2)) + 0
    let l:b = ("0x" . strpart(a:rgb, 4, 2)) + 0

    return <SID>colour(l:r, l:g, l:b)
endfun

" Sets the highlighting for the given group
fun <SID>X(group, fg, bg, attr)
    if a:fg != ""
        exec "hi " . a:group . " guifg=#" . a:fg . " ctermfg=" . <SID>rgb(a:fg)
    endif
    if a:bg != ""
        exec "hi " . a:group . " guibg=#" . a:bg . " ctermbg=" . <SID>rgb(a:bg)
    endif
    if a:attr != ""
        exec "hi " . a:group . " gui=" . a:attr . " cterm=" . a:attr
    endif
endfun

" Vim Highlighting
call <SID>X("Normal", s:foreground, s:background, "")
call <SID>X("LineNr", s:selection, "", "")
call <SID>X("NonText", s:selection, "", "")
call <SID>X("SpecialKey", s:selection, "", "")
call <SID>X("Search", s:background, s:yellow, "")
call <SID>X("TabLine", s:foreground, s:background, "reverse")
call <SID>X("StatusLine", s:window, s:yellow, "reverse")
call <SID>X("StatusLineNC", s:window, s:foreground, "reverse")
call <SID>X("VertSplit", s:window, s:window, "none")
call <SID>X("Visual", "", s:selection, "")
call <SID>X("Directory", s:blue, "", "")
call <SID>X("ModeMsg", s:green, "", "")
call <SID>X("MoreMsg", s:green, "", "")
call <SID>X("Question", s:green, "", "")
call <SID>X("WarningMsg", s:red, "", "")
call <SID>X("MatchParen", "", s:selection, "")
call <SID>X("Folded", s:comment, s:background, "")
call <SID>X("FoldColumn", "", s:background, "")
if version >= 700
    call <SID>X("CursorLine", "", s:line, "none")
    call <SID>X("CursorColumn", "", s:line, "none")
    call <SID>X("PMenu", s:foreground, s:selection, "none")
    call <SID>X("PMenuSel", s:foreground, s:selection, "reverse")
end
if version >= 703
    call <SID>X("ColorColumn", "", s:line, "none")
end

" Standard Highlighting
call <SID>X("Comment", s:comment, "", "")
call <SID>X("Todo", s:comment, s:background, "")
call <SID>X("Title", s:comment, "", "")
call <SID>X("Identifier", s:red, "", "none")
call <SID>X("Statement", s:foreground, "", "")
call <SID>X("Conditional", s:foreground, "", "")
call <SID>X("Repeat", s:foreground, "", "")
call <SID>X("Structure", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("Function", s:blue, "", "")
call <SID>X("Constant", s:orange, "", "")
call <SID>X("String", s:green, "", "")
call <SID>X("Special", s:foreground, "", "")
call <SID>X("PreProc", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("Operator", s:aqua, "", "none")
call <SID>X("Type", s:blue, "", "none")
call <SID>X("Define", s:purple, "", "none")
call <SID>X("Include", s:blue, "", "")
"call <SID>X("Ignore", "666666", "", "")

" Vim Highlighting
call <SID>X("vimCommand", s:red, "", "none")

" C Highlighting
call <SID>X("cType", s:yellow, "", "")
call <SID>X("cStorageClass", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("cConditional", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("cRepeat", s:purple, "", "")

" PHP Highlighting
call <SID>X("phpVarSelector", s:red, "", "")
call <SID>X("phpKeyword", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("phpRepeat", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("phpConditional", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("phpStatement", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("phpMemberSelector", s:foreground, "", "")

" Ruby Highlighting
call <SID>X("rubySymbol", s:green, "", "")
call <SID>X("rubyConstant", s:yellow, "", "")
call <SID>X("rubyAttribute", s:blue, "", "")
call <SID>X("rubyInclude", s:blue, "", "")
call <SID>X("rubyLocalVariableOrMethod", s:orange, "", "")
call <SID>X("rubyCurlyBlock", s:orange, "", "")
call <SID>X("rubyStringDelimiter", s:green, "", "")
call <SID>X("rubyInterpolationDelimiter", s:orange, "", "")
call <SID>X("rubyConditional", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("rubyRepeat", s:purple, "", "")

" Python Highlighting
call <SID>X("pythonInclude", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("pythonStatement", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("pythonConditional", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("pythonFunction", s:blue, "", "")

" JavaScript Highlighting
call <SID>X("javaScriptBraces", s:foreground, "", "")
call <SID>X("javaScriptFunction", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("javaScriptConditional", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("javaScriptRepeat", s:purple, "", "")
call <SID>X("javaScriptNumber", s:orange, "", "")
call <SID>X("javaScriptMember", s:orange, "", "")

" HTML Highlighting
call <SID>X("htmlTag", s:red, "", "")
call <SID>X("htmlTagName", s:red, "", "")
call <SID>X("htmlArg", s:red, "", "")
call <SID>X("htmlScriptTag", s:red, "", "")

" Diff Highlighting
call <SID>X("diffAdded", s:green, "", "")
call <SID>X("diffRemoved", s:red, "", "")

" Delete Functions
delf <SID>X
delf <SID>rgb
delf <SID>colour
delf <SID>rgb_colour
delf <SID>rgb_level
delf <SID>rgb_number
delf <SID>grey_colour
delf <SID>grey_level
delf <SID>grey_number
endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to the C Highlighting paragraph:

```
call <SID>X("Statement", s:purple, "", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

All the keywords you mention eventually link to the standard `Statement` syntax group. Maybe that one got cleared. Try

```
:verbose highlight Statement
```

If it shows `xxx cleared`, you're one step further and now need to investigate why your colorscheme does not define a coloring.

Comment: it shows this: Statement      xxx term=bold ctermfg=254 gui=bold guifg=#eaeaea
Last set from ~/.vim/colors/Tomorrow-Night-Bright.vim

Comment: What does it show for `:verbose hi cppStatement`? Does it link to `Statement`?

Comment: yes, it links to statement: cppStatement   xxx links to Statement

Comment: And the keywords aren't colored bold + light grey? Then something seems to override the syntax highlighting. For further troubleshooting, I would recommend the SyntaxAttr plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383